# Is it wrong to give a specific time when asked for your availability for an interview?

Tags: interviewing

I recently had an interview with a recruiter. The interview was ok and today I received an email about a follow-up interview. The interviewer asked for my availability for the next week.

I replied "Is it ok to have the interview on Monday at 10:00?". He did not reply to my email. The working hours are over and I don't think he will be working tomorrow as its Saturday.

Do you think it was rude of me to mention a specific time for the interview instead of mentioning the days I am available ?

**EDIT:** Its already Monday and I have not received any answer from him. How long should I wait before contacting him ?

Comment: Is this a 3rd party/contract recruiter or does he work for the company where you're applying for the job?

Comment: He works for the company

Comment: I would expect a response to "what is your availability" to be a range of times or days. If you have a busy schedule and are only available for a short period, you should explicitly state that that is the only time that works for you.

Comment: Well other times work for me too but this seemed like the best time. Thats why I asked him if it was ok.

Comment: @DavidK Do you think I should apologize to him ?

Comment: At this point, just wait to see how he responds. In the future, you should give them some flexibility. Say "10am is the best time for me, but I would be able to do anytime between 9am and noon".

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Wrong as in it could result in me losing the interview ?

Comment: When booking appointments give the person a little "wiggle" room. i.e. Say Morning would be grate or perhaps Tuesday afternoon.

Comment: see [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 7):

Not rude, but perhaps not the best way to respond. Asking if the time is OK makes you seem timid and insecure, and also puts the onus on the recruiter to respond to confirm your question.

Better to say something like "Monday at 10 would be best for me, but I am flexible to meet at other times. Please let me know if that time doesn't work." Also would be good to give a range of days and times, since flexibility increases your chances of getting the interview.

That said, I don't think your email is anything to worry about -- I would simply wait a few days to see what the recruiter's response is.

Comment: "timid and insecure" if you're apply for lumberjack, bouncer, professional wrestler, long shore man, or school bus driver.

Comment: " Asking if the time is OK makes you seem timid and insecure" - disagree. Assuming it's done in a professional manner, I think it makes you seem polite.

Answer (score 6):

Step one, relax. ;-).

For future reference, here's a good method:

"I'm available Monday through Wednesday before noon. How is 10am on Monday?"

The does a bit of work:

It's flexible. 
It establishes your preference. 
It doesn't just kick the ball back to them for a decision. 
It is definitive without being pushy. 
It allows a "yes" answer.

You probably have more detailed availability, but this is a balance of simple, decisive and flexible.

For now, the ball is in their court. Let them make the next move.

Comment: I like "Step one, relax".  Be calm and cool at the workplace and in life is always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think anything is wrong with the way you responded. If the recruiter feels he will need a few more slots to have more flexibility, he will let you know. You answered very simply and directly to his question of what time suits you best.So relax, and wait for him to respond. And make sure you have figured out some time slots that work for you and days so that you can give him / her more options and flexibility. All the best for the interview!

Answer (score 0):

An inteview is likely to involve multiple people. At least some of those people are likely more senior than you (iirc at my current job it was my immediate boss, the head of group and someone from outside the group) and have multiple responsibilities and of course the company will likely be interviewing multiple candidates for the posision so will want to do the interviews in blocks.

So giving a single time is unlikely to be very helpful. It might work out for everyone but it's more likely that it won't.

Given that it's friday and you asked about mondayy i'd say your best bet now is to wait and see if you get a reply by early monday morning (some people do check work email over the weekend). If not then I would send another mail detailing your availability (and possiblly expressing some preference but try not to get too detailed on that)